# What happens when my incomer main and generators are operated together without an interlock ?

Tags: electrical

Suppose consider my incomer main is live and is feeding my MCC and now if i operate my standby diesel generator connected to the MCC what will happen in the system ?? will there be dead shorts or any other type of problem ?

Comment: After the power company tracks down the fact that you are the guy trying to kill their linemen, they disconnect your "incomer main" and refuse to supply you with any power...please stop asking "what happens when I do this homicidally dangerous mind-bogglingly stupid thing?" Either get an interlock, or have your connection to the power company removed, or get rid of your generator before you kill someone.

Answer (score 6):

There could be worse than a dead short.  If the generators are out of phase significantly at the point they are connected, they will be consolidating their momentum which almost certainly means your generator will be destroyed in 1/50 or 1/60 of a second, unless an unusually fast circuit breaker can isolate it in time.

Also, if the external power is cut and your system backfeeds the main, it will try to run your neighbors appliances—at a time they are expecting no power possibly causing severe shock or injury.  Also, linemen making repairs upstream can be seriously injured by power being applied when they operated a disconnected and expect dead wires.

Comment: dear wallyk, Thank you so much for taking concern in replying me. What if when my generators are in phase with the incomer line to the MCC ?

Comment: Then they won't **stay** in phase.

Comment: They won't be in phase. Just stop considering doing this before you end up destroying your generator. Well, at least the bright side there would be that you could no longer kill someone with it if you ruined it.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - Unlike a synchronizing sine-wave inverter for Solar power which is meant to feed power back into the grid (other safety mechanisms in place), there's no mechanism in a standard genset to synch to the grid. They never were intended to. So, really good point as two generation systems feeding in at 180 degrees out of phase are effectively seeing a dead short.